# D3 JS Data Filtering

Tags: d3.js

Im trying to filter a dataset to only display labels for some select elements.  The filter shown here seems to work, except it creates thousands of blank  elements, which I obviously want to avoid.  This is because the filter comes after the append, but if I move the filter above the append statement , it breaks.

What am i doing wrong here

```
  var labels = svg.selectAll("text.label")
    .data(partition.nodes(bp.data.preparedData))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .filter(function(d){return d.ci_type === 'type'})
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .text(function(d, i) { return d.name } );
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like you want to filter your data before passing it to D3. That is, your code would be

```
var labels = svg.selectAll("text.label")
   .data(partition.nodes(bp.data.preparedData).filter(
            function(d){return d.ci_type === 'type'}))
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("class", "label")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
   .text(function(d, i) { return d.name } );
```