# D3js data selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use this fiddle to filter out data by following this thread

[D3 JS Data Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244857/d3-js-data-filtering)

My fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/WthG7/)

I am trying to do something like this

```
var svg = d3.select('#ReportContent_ReportContent svg')
    .data(data).filter(function (v) {
    return data.Product === "Lending";
})
    .attr("class", "bullet")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(chart);
```

my data looks like this

```
var data = [{
    "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00",
        "Product": "Fee Based",
        "Actual": [1002],
        "Forecast": [1200],
        "Target": [1400]
}, {
    "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00",
        "Product": "Lending",
        "Actual": [8146873.33],
        "Forecast": [7220309.99],
        "Target": [7220309.995]
}];
```

I wanted to pick the 'Lending', for example but what I am trying doesnt work. Could anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WthG7/1/) with the correct syntax and data.

```
.data(data.filter(function(d) {return d.Product === 'Lending';}))
```

You can change the filtering criterium between 'Fee Based' and 'Lending' to see it at work.